# Automatically publishing cloud service to Azure using TFS15

Tags: azure, tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

I've spent the past few days working on a build system that can continuously deploy a website to a staging system on Azure.  I believe I'm pretty close to having it work, however I get an error when Azure tries to provision the website using the MSDeploy extension.

**Overview of my Process:**

Using Team Foundation Server 2015 (Self-hosted, not VSO), I created a build definition which has a "Visual Studio Build" step:

[image]

This runs MSBuild with the arguments:

> /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package
>   /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true

This creates a ZIP file called WebRole1.zip which can be found at `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\AzureTestBuilds\WebRole1.zip`

[Link to ZIP if anyone cares](http://538f86488c3e2f38f493-eb0b7d0bc604fdc4c9a517c48ddd0ad7.r55.cf2.rackcdn.com/WebRole1.zip)

Next, the build uses a Powershell script to connect to Azure, upload the above ZIP file to a storage blob, and provision the site using a JSON based template.  The template has the following MSDeploy extension to deploy the site:

```
   "resources": [
      {
          "apiVersion": "2014-06-01",
          "type": "Extensions",
          "name": "MSDeploy",
          "dependsOn": [
              "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('WebAPIURL'))]"
          ],
          "properties": {
            "packageUri": "[concat(variables('SiteStagingStorageURL'), '/zips/WebRole1.zip', parameters('sasToken'))]",
            "dbType": "None",
            "connectionString": "",
            "setParameters": {
              "Application Path": "[variables('WebAPIURL')]"
            }
          }
      }
   ]
```

When the build runs, I get the following error:

> 4:21:31 PM - Resource Microsoft.Web/sites/Extensions
>   'xxx-WebAPI/MSDeploy' failed with message 'The resource operation
>   completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.'

Within Kudu (The Azure diagnostic console), I see a more detailed error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<entries>
    <entry time="2016-02-13T00:21:51.3365955+00:00" type="Message">
        <message>Downloading metadata for package path 'zips/WebRole1.zip' from blob 'https://xxx.blob.core.windows.net'</message>
    </entry>
    <entry time="2016-02-13T00:21:51.8023866+00:00" type="Message">
        <message>The blob has flag IsPremiumApp:. IsPremiumApp returns False</message>
    </entry>
    <entry time="2016-02-13T00:21:51.8805277Z" type="Message">
        <message>Downloading package path 'zips/WebRole1.zip' from blob 'https://xxx.blob.core.windows.net'</message>
    </entry>
    <entry time="2016-02-13T00:21:52.2711541Z" type="Error">
        <message>AppGallery Deploy Failed: 'Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentXmlException: The declared parameter 'Application Path' is not recognized.

   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncParameterCollection.LoadFromFile(XPathNavigator nav, String fileName, Boolean ignoreExtraSetParameters)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncParameterCollection.LoadXml(String xml)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi.AppGalleryPackage.LoadSetParameters(DeploymentObject deploymentObject, IDictionary`2 setParams)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi.AppGalleryPackage.Deploy(String deploymentSite, String siteSlotId)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi.DeploymentController.&lt;DownloadAndDeployPackage&gt;d__b.MoveNext()'</message>
    </entry>
</entries>
```

From what I can tell, the parameters within the zip's XML manifest are incorrect.  I've spent a lot of time reading various blogs and tutorials about how to deploy a site on Azure using the MSDeploy build extension, but all of them use an existing *sample* ZIP file.  I can't find any information on the correct format for these zip files and the XML manifest, nor how to create a valid one using MSBuild.  Is there a step I'm missing here?  I'm happy to post any more information needed.

Comment: The error message indicated "The declared parameter 'Application Path' is not recognized", did you try to change the parameter 'Application Path'?

Comment: If you're up for it, TFS 2015 Update 2 is in Release Candidate with a go-live license (https://www.visualstudio.com/news/tfs2015-update2-vs) and it includes the new web based release management functionality currently available on VSTS.  It makes this kind of thing really easy and better still, you can decouple your build and release processes.

Comment: @rerwinRR - Oh, that looks promising.  I am running TFS15, wonder how easy the "upgrade" process is.  It's running on a VM, so I can just take a snapshot and revert back if I screw everything up..

Comment: @Cece-MSFT - Sorry, I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: @MikeChristensen, sorry I'm not familiar with JSON Syntax, but as the log complains the declared parameter 'Application Path', you may try to give 'Application Path' a specific value to see whether you would get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out.  I had to add a file called `parameters.xml` to the root folder of the project (same folder as `web.config` and `Global.asax`.  The file contains the following:

```
<parameters>
  <parameter name="Application Path" description="Full site path where you would like to install your application (i.e., Default Web Site/WebRole1)" defaultValue="Default Web Site/WebRole1" tags="iisapp">
    <parameterEntry type="ProviderPath" scope="iisapp" match="WebRole1" />
  </parameter>
  <parameter name="SetAclParameter1" description="Hidden - automatically sets write access for the app" defaultValue="{Application Path}/App_Data" tags="Hidden, NoDatabase">
    <parameterEntry type="ProviderPath" scope="setAcl" match="WebRole1/App_Data" />
  </parameter>
</parameters>
```

Change `WebRole1` to whatever the name of your web project is.  MSDeploy seems to just pick up this file automatically, no need to change any other settings or build parameters.

Answer (score 0):

JSON values can be:

```
A number (integer or floating point)
A string (in double quotes)
A Boolean (true or false)
An array (in square brackets)
An object (in curly braces)
null
```

But it seems you are using a Function (variables('WebAPIURL')) in the value field. I'm afraid it's the issue.